# How do I extract a field from this XML using XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xslt, namespaces

I'm an XSLT newbie, and need to use XSLT to extract some fields from a trademark file from the US Patent and Trademark Office.  Here's a very simplified copy of a typical file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Transaction xmlns:ns2="urn:us:gov:doc:uspto:trademark:status" xmlns="http://www.wipo.int/standards/XMLSchema/trademarks">
  <TradeMarkTransactionBody>
    <TransactionContentDetails>
      <TransactionCode>National Trademark Information</TransactionCode>
      <TransactionData>
        <TradeMarkDetails>
          <TradeMark>
            <RegistrationOfficeCode>US</RegistrationOfficeCode>
            <ApplicationNumber>74631225</ApplicationNumber>
            <ApplicationDate>1995-02-07-05:00</ApplicationDate>
            <RegistrationNumber>2178784</RegistrationNumber>
            <RegistrationDate>1998-08-04-04:00</RegistrationDate>
            <FilingPlace>US</FilingPlace>
            <MarkCurrentStatusDate>2008-08-11-04:00</MarkCurrentStatusDate>
            <WordMarkSpecification>
              <MarkVerbalElementText>JAVA </MarkVerbalElementText>
            </WordMarkSpecification>
          </TradeMark>
        </TradeMarkDetails>
      </TransactionData>
    </TransactionContentDetails>
  </TradeMarkTransactionBody>
</Transaction>
```

I would like to be able to produce:

```
App number: 74631225
```

Here are a couple of my failed attempts;  Attempt #1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
    App number: <xsl:value-of select="/Transaction/TradeMarkTransactionBody/TransactionContentDetails/TransactionData/TradeMarkDetails/TradeMark/ApplicationNumber"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces only:

```
App number:
```

Attempt #2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />
    <xsl:template match="/Transaction/TradeMarkTransactionBody/TransactionContentDetails/TransactionData/TradeMarkDetails/TradeMark">
    App number: <xsl:value-of select="ApplicationNumber"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces:

```
  National Trademark Information



        US
        74631225
        1995-02-07-05:00
        2178784
        1998-08-04-04:00
        US
        2008-08-11-04:00

          JAVA
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Once I get past this gate and have at least one field working, I hope I can get into the real substance of my project.  If it matters, I'm using both MSXSL and Treebeard (which uses Saxon, I think) for my testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XSLT code is missing the namespace declaration. Check out the root element in your Xml document, it says this:

```
xmlns="http://www.wipo.int/standards/XMLSchema/trademarks"
```

That means, any of the elements in your Xml document are in that namespace.

In the XSLTs, on the other hand, you did not specify any namespace, which means that your XSLT processor looks for element names specified in the XSLT with the "blank namespace" - so e.g. `Transaction` mentioned in your XSLT is not the same element as `Transaction` (from the `http://www.wipo.int/standards/XMLSchema/trademarks` namespace) mentioned in your Xml document.

XSLT, or rather XPath, does not know the concept of a "default" (prefix-less) namespace, which is why you will have to assign some arbitrary prefix - say `tm`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:tm="http://www.wipo.int/standards/XMLSchema/trademarks">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
    App number: <xsl:value-of select="/tm:Transaction/tm:TradeMarkTransactionBody/tm:TransactionContentDetails/tm:TransactionData/tm:TradeMarkDetails/tm:TradeMark/tm:ApplicationNumber"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

*This should get you a step closer to what you are looking for. I can try this only in a few hours from now; if you need further assistance, please leave a comment and I'll check back on this question.*